# Example of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I am looking to construct an example of sequence of functions such that

$s_k =0$ outside of $[0,1]$, $\lim s_k = 0$ and $\lim \int s_k d\lambda$ = $\infty$

In my attempt I came up with the following sequence

$f_k(x)=\begin{cases}
       k, &\quad\text{if } - \frac{1}{k} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{k}\\
       0, &\quad\text{elsewhere} \ 
     \end{cases}$

Now with this sequence I get $\int f_kdm=\frac{2}{k}(k)=2, \forall k$

But I want to construct a sequence $\lim \int s_k d\lambda$ = $\infty$ which this does not satisfy.

I am looking to generate this sequence to complete a negation of some other problem  namely , that the conclusion of fatou's lemma cannot be strengthened to equality.

Comment: Consider $$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}k^2 & \text{if }0 < x < 1/k \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Bungo , Won't the integral of this be equal to zero though ?

Comment: No. $ \int f_k d\lambda = \int_{0}^{1/k} k^2 d\lambda=k$.

Comment: It's the area of a rectangle of height $k^2$ and width $1/k$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks I got it now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something continuous then $f_n(x)=nx^n$ and $f_n(x)=n(1-x)^n$ are classical examples of non convergence to zero in $L^1$.

They works with the same principle than Bungo's proposal, it goes negligeable quickly on any interval $[0,1-\varepsilon]$ (resp. $[\varepsilon,1]$) but have a peak in $x=1$ (resp. $x=0$) which is the main contribution to the integral.

Though you want something which has limit $0$ and previous examples don't since $f(1)\nrightarrow 0$ (resp. $f(0)\nrightarrow 0$) but this is easily fixed.

For instance consider $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid]{f_n(x)=n^3(1-x)x^n}$ with this one $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and the peak is sliding toward $1$.

***We call this a sliding hump***.

It is easy to see that with the factor $n^3$ the integral diverges

$\displaystyle{\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=n^3\left[\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}\right]_0^1=\frac{n^3}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sim n\to+\infty}$

Also $|f_n(x)|\le n^3x^n\to 0$ when $x<1$, and in $1$ the factor $(1-x)$ takes care about $f(1)=0$.

Another example I can think of, would be something like $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid]{f_n(x)=n^2\;e^{-n(nx-1)^2}}$

This is a very smooth function, it decreases quickly to zero away from $x=\frac 1n$ (near $0$ it is $\sim e^{-n}$, near $1$ it is $\sim e^{-n^3x^2}$).

This is again a sliding hump kind, but this time the integral is frightening, anyway, according to maple (which I will trust on this...) with a factor $n^2$ then $\int f_n\sim\sqrt{\pi n}\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
k^2 & \text{if }0 < x < 1/k \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$
You can easily check that

1. $\int f_k(x)\ dx = k$, hence $\lim_{k \to \infty}\int f_k(x)\ dx = \infty$
2. $\lim_{k \to \infty}f_k(x) = 0$ for all $x$
3. $f_k(x) = 0$ for all $x$ outside of $[0,1]$

Note that your proposed sequence did not satisfy any of these criteria.