# Find sequence of function that has several conditions

Tags: integration, sequence-of-function

$\require{cancel}$I have to find a sequence of function $f_n(x)$ that would have these conditions:

1. $f_n(x)$ is continious in the range  $[0;1]$
2. $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$, $x\in[0,1]\; \forall{x}$
3. $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\, dx \cancel{\rightarrow}0$

Comment: Try $n^2(1-x)x^n$.

Comment: @Kelenner this sequence of function doesn't satisfy the second condition, because it has a maximum point in the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: Slightly different request on the integral, but same principle https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178698/example-of-a-sequence-of-functions/2178986#2178986

Comment: @Jonas it has indeed a maximum point, but this point is sliding toward $1$, yet $f_n(1)=0$ so $f_n\to 0$.

Comment: @JonasVitkauskas In condition 2, I assume you mean pointwise convergence instead of uniform convergence, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer by @Kelenner above, here is a family of functions that have the same non-zero integral for all $n$:

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
4n^2x, &0\le x < \frac1{2n},\\
2n, &x = \frac1{2n},\\
4n^2\left(\frac1n-x\right), &\frac1{2n}<x<\frac1n,\\
0, &\frac1n \le x \le 1.
\end{cases}$$

Condition 2 is satisfied, because $\forall x\in(0,1]$, $$n\ge\frac1x\implies f_n(x) = 0,$$

and $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, $f_n(0) = 0$.

Condition 3 is satisfied:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f_n(x)\ dx
&= \int_0^\frac1{2n}4n^2x\ dx + \int_{\frac1{2n}}^{\frac1n} 4n^2\left(\frac1n-x\right)dx\\
&= 2\int_0^\frac1{2n}4n^2x\ dx\\
&= 2\cdot4n^2\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{(2n)^2}\\
&= 1\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\ dx &\ne 0
\end{align*}$$